# Creating a trie (or tree) for a branch and bound multiple TSP

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, graph-algorithm, trie

I'm struggling with increasing the speed of my pseudo branch & bound algo & thought a trie structure might be a good fit, but I'm stuck.

**The problem (simplified & isolated best I can):**

I've got 9 nodes & 3 vehicles. Each vehicle must visit 3 unique nodes. So, I created every possible trip (9 choose 3 = 84) & stuck it in an array. Now, I want to find every combination.
For example, trip 1 could be `111000000`. trip 2 would be `000110001` and trip 3 would be `000001110`. (84^3 = 592704 combinations).
To find out if they match, I just do a bitwise `&` and accept the trip combination if the value is 0.

I can't use nested loops since the # of vehicles may change, so I keep track of combinations with a counter that ticks up depth-wise like an odometer (e.g. `0,0,82`, `0,0,83`, `0,1,0`).

I reduce combinations by keeping the following digit greater than the one that just increased (e.g. `11,83,83` goes to `12,13,14` because anything less than a `12` in the 2nd column would be a repeat like `12,1,1` is a duplicate of `1,1,12`).

I also perform the bitwise AND check at each change (e.g. if `(val[12] & val[13]) > 0` don't bother checking the 71 possibilities in the 3rd column, because the 12 and 13 invalidate the route. This reduces the combinations to 24720.

Since I'm doing depth-first, it's really space efficient (no queue to save), but computationally expensive. What I'd like to do is use a width-first approach to create subsets and minimize the search space. For example, assume the counter was at `11,19,20`. Currently, it would check 20 - 83 in the 3rd column before incrementing the 19 to a 20. I would like to compute the AND for 19 - 83 in the 2nd column before moving on. In doing so, I would know all the values that don't work with the `11` in the first column and could use that subarray for the 3rd column (e.g. if `(val[11] & val[45]) > 0`, don't bother checking `11 & 19 & 45`, rather use an array that excludes 45 from the 3rd column.

My idea is to create a trie, where each key is the result of the AND operation with an `end` key that would be the subarray.

For example:

```
doc = {
    1: {
        5: {
            end: [8,9,10]
        },
        7: {
            end: [11,14,42]
        },
        end: [81, 13, 42]
    }
}
```

My problem is I can't for the life of me figure out how to iterate over my data to grow the trie. Or maybe there's a better approach? Any advice or code snippets would be great, and thanks for reading through the wall of text.

Comment: Just to clarify:  Are you trying to enumerate all the possible of nodes to vehicles ?  You say that the number of vehicles is subject to change.  How about calling it n, then?  Is the total number of nodes subject to change, too? Is it expected to be equal to 3*n ?  
Nitpick: there are 84 possibilities, so you should go from 0 to 83, not 84.

Comment: Right you are, fixed! Yes, number of vehicles can change as can number of nodes & it won't always be equal to 3n, i just used that for the example.